# How to disable layout usage in Dust Template engine

Tags: node.js, dust.js, kraken.js

1- Is there any default layout settings in Dust template engine ?

How can I disable usage of layout altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are refering to adaro (which is used to render templates in kraken) you can simply pass `false` to the `layout` property. [Documented here](https://github.com/krakenjs/adaro#user-content-layout-optional-string-sets-default-template-to-use-for-layout)

A layout typically refers to a template with the special partial `{>"{_main}"/}`

This "wrapper" can be disabled:

```
// Disable layout altogether
dust.render('index', { layout: false }, ...);
```

Hope this helps.
Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean {+placholder} and {<inlinepartial} as these are the mechanisms of layout for dust. I know of no way to disable it but other than preventing your users from using this, why would you want to disable it? It doesn't really cost anything if you don't use it.